# Reactjs to change the state of a component based on child component's class

Tags: reactjs

I have been using reactjs now for quite sometime, and so far going really good. However there is one thing i have kind of gotten stuck with. I am trying to change the state of the parent component on click but only if the child component has a certain class, not otherwise.

Let me provide you a sample of the code here:

Parent component:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      pageState: false
    }
  }

  changeState(){
    this.setState({pageState: !this.state.pageState});
  }

  render(){
    return(

      <div id="app">
        <ul>
          <Child sendState={this.changeState.bind(this)} heading="Home"/>
          <Child sendState={this.changeState.bind(this)} heading="About"/>
          <Child sendState={this.changeState.bind(this)} heading="Contact"/>
          <Child sendState={this.changeState.bind(this)} heading="Work"/>
        </ul>
      </div>

    )
  }

}

render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById("app-wrapper"));
```

Child component

```
class Child extends React.Component{

 render(){
  return(
    <li className="list_element">
     <div className="card_block" onClick={this.props.sendState.bind(this)}>
      <h2>{this.props.heading}</h2>
     </div>
    <li>
  )
 }
}
```

So basically what i am trying to achieve is, when the card inside the "li" is clicked, the state needs to change, but only if the parent "li" has a 'current' class. So onclick of the card element, check it's class, and if it has "current" class, change the state.

Is there anyway this can be made possible?

Comment: you can try passing callback function as prop to the child. https://www.codementor.io/ryan286/passing-functions-as-react-props-9fimj8ikv

Comment: Did you mean, while on clicking the div you need to check the class of `ul` or the component `<Parent />` ?

Comment: Just create another state, indicating whether or not the parent has the 'current' state. Then in the onClick method in the child, only call `this.props.sendState` if the parent has the 'current' state.

Comment: Well onclick of the <div> inside the <li> i need to check if the <li> has the current class, if yes, change the state, so is there a way to pass the "className" property to "stateChange" function? i mean if that can be done, then this function can check whether the clicked element or it's parent has the "current" class, if so change the state, else don't change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `className` as props to your `<Parent />` component from a click event handler inside the `<Child />` component. Try following code by making necessary changes in the comments.
Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kartalerkoc/rfra9uep/3/

Update: based on your comment regarding JQuery, I updated the `<Child />` component's `onClickCard()` and `render()` methods to use `refs` for your question. Also, updated the fiddle.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageState: false
    }
    // bind this to your changeState function
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }

  // Revise your changeState function
  changeState(textClassName){
    if (textClassName.includes("current")) {
      console.log("true - current is in class name");
        this.setState({pageState: !this.state.pageState});
    }
  }

  // edit the prop function for <Child />
  render(){
    return(
      <div id="app">
        <ul>
          <Child heading={"Home"} changeState={this.changeState} />
          <Child heading={"About"} changeState={this.changeState} />
          <Child heading={"Contact"} changeState={this.changeState} />
          <Child heading={"Work"} changeState={this.changeState} />
        </ul>
      </div>

    )
  }

}

class Child extends React.Component{
 // add onClick event handler for card
 onClickCard() {
    let refValue = "li"+this.props.heading;
    let textClassName = this.refs[refValue].className;
    this.props.changeState(textClassName);
 };

 // Edit your onClick event handler on div element
 render(){
 let refValue = "li"+this.props.heading;
 console.log(refValue);
  return(
    <li className={"list_element current"} id={refValue} ref={refValue}>
     <div className="card_block" onClick={this.onClickCard.bind(this)}>
      <h2>{this.props.heading}</h2>
     </div>
   </li>
  )
 }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app-wrapper'));
```

Comment: Basically, the "current" class is getting added to the parent <li> once the <li> is in view using jquery... i am gonna give this one a try...

Comment: I have updated the `onClickCard()` function and the `render()` method inside the `Child` component. Also, updated the fiddle. But, be aware that refValues should be each unique as they are id for elements. Also, normally you shouldn't need JQuery to manipulate className when you are using React.

Comment: I had a look at the fiddle... and inspected it to take a look at the DOM structure, it seems like all the <li> have "current" class :/ i am a little confused. Apologies if i am pointing out something that's incorrect here, but i am a bit confused about this lil thing :/ Because current class is initally not added, it's only added after some event is triggered, and added only to the <li>currently in view, not the others...:/

Comment: Don't worry, it is actually better that you ask for clarification. So, here I simulate the case where you already triggered the event that adds "current" to class of <li> element. So just remove the "current" from className and try it. Because your trigger will add "current" to className later. No problems. The thing is here to use `ref` attribute in React. Please ask again if you have any other question also.

Comment: Thanks :) I am gonna try this and if there are any more clarifications needed, will surely let you know... :)

Comment: It worked!!! it helped me achieve what i had been trying to do all this while... :) Thanks Kartal :)

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)